# Rate of convergence for Newton's method for the Approximation of the Lambert W function

Tags: convergence-divergence, approximation, lambert-w, newton-raphson

**How quickly does Newton's Method for the [approximation of the Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Numerical_evaluation) converge?**

$$w_{j+1}=w_j-\frac{w_je^{w_j}-x}{e^{w_j}+w_je^{w_j}}$$

or simplified:

$$w_{j+1}=\frac{xe^{-w_j}+w_j^2}{w_j+1}$$

where $x$ replaces $z$ in the equation, because I'm only concerned with real numbers.

I understand that given $\infty$ iterations, it will converge to be absolutely accurate.

For example, after $n$ iteration, it will be accurate to $m$ decimal places.

Comment: In connection with your previous question (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1950644). I think that instead of deleting this question, you could have asked this second question in the same framework. Moreover, I advise you to try to have an idea by numerical computations and ask us in a second step how you can improve the accuracy.

Comment: @JeanMarie I deleted that other question because I found the solution on my own, and didn't think it merited me "answering" the question there. (If anything, the first part of my question was a duplicate, and the second part belongs on Stack Overflow more than here)

Comment: Technically speaking, have you considered simplifying your recurrence expression as $w_{j+1}=\frac{w_j^2+xe^{-w_j}}{1+w_j}$ in order to improve its analysis and moreover its convergence speed ?

Comment: Most numerical approximation methods increase the number of digits accurate by doubling or tripling, or in some way along those lines.  For example, I do think the number of digits accurate when solving $x=\sqrt{c}$ doubles per iteration, once convergence sets in.

Comment: @Simple Art Not *most* numericalapproximation methods ; quadratic convergence is almost specific to Newton's method...

Comment: @JeanMarie No, I meant that they usually have a set convergence rate per approximation method.

Comment: **I have updated my question, asking something that gets more to the point.**

Comment: Roughly speaking, once you have a single correct digit, in the next iteration you will have twice as many, then twice as many again, etc. This is because the derivative of $f(w)=we^w-x$ does not vanish. You can be a bit more precise by estimating the actual constant factor in the quadratic convergence.

Comment: You can do that as follows: $x-x^*-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=\frac{f(x)-f'(x)(x-x^*)}{f'(x)}=\frac{f'(x^*)(x-x^*)+\frac{1}{2} f''(x_1)(x-x^*)^2-(f'(x^*)+f''(x_2)(x-x^*))(x-x^*)}{f'(x)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2} f''(x_1)(x-x^*)^2-f''(x_2)(x-x^*)^2}{f'(x)}$. So $|x_{k+1}-x^*| \leq C |x_k-x^*|^2$ where $C$ is an upper bound on $\frac{3}{2} \frac{|f''|}{|f'|}$ on a neighborhood of $x^*$. Thus you can take $C$ to be $\frac{3}{2} \frac{W(x) e^{W(x)} + 2W(x)}{W(x) e^{W(x)}+W(x)}$. As usual the problem with this is that the error estimate involves the quantity being approximated...

Comment: But of course there are ways around that too. For example, if $x \geq e$ then $W(x) \leq \ln(x)$, so that $C \leq \frac{3}{2} \left ( 1+\frac{\ln(x)}{x \ln(x)+\ln(x)} \right )$. On the other hand, if $0 \leq x \leq e$ then $W(x) \leq x$ so that $C \leq \frac{3}{2} \left ( 1+\frac{x}{xe^x+x} \right )$.

Comment: @Ian Say that I have a calculator that computes the value of $W(x)$ to $n$ decimal places. How can I calculate how many iterations to do until it exceeds the accuracy of $n$ decimal places?

Comment: It depends on the accuracy of the initial guess and on what the input is. Say for illustration that you just want to write a calculator for $0 \leq x \leq e$ and you take your initial guess to be $1/2$ no matter what the input is. Then the analysis above says that given $k$ correct binary places, after an iteration you now have about $2k-1$ correct binary places.

Comment: Thus after $n$ iterations when starting with $2$ correct binary digits you have $1+2^n$ correct binary digits. You always have $1$ correct binary digit in this range of inputs with this guess, but it could potentially take several iterations before you have two correct digits.

Comment: It is clear that the root $w$ satisfies $w < x$. In that case, it's better to write $w = \lambda x$ such that your equation becomes $\lambda\exp\left(\lambda x\right) - 1 = 0$ and you can start with $\lambda_{0} = (0 + 1)/2 = 1/2$. However, because $\lambda \in \left(0,1\right)$ it's convenient to use a $Bisection\ Method$.