# Averaging Newton's Method and Halley's Method

Tags: approximation, lambert-w, newton-raphson

To approximate the Lambert W function, one can use Newton's Method:

$$w_{j+1}=w_j-\frac{w_je^{w_j}-x}{e^{w_j}+w_je^{w_j}}$$

Or use Halley's Method:

$$w_{j+1}=-\frac{w_je^{w_j}-x}{e^{w_j}(w_j+1)-\frac{(w_j+2)(w_je^{w_j}-x)}{2w_j+2}}$$

Are these two methods identical? / Do they return the same result per iteration?

If not, would averaging the value of these after each iteration make the approximation more accurate?

*(This question is related, but tangent to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952626/accuracy-of-newtons-method-for-approximating-the-lambert-w-function) of mine that is also about Newton's method and the Lambert W function)*

Comment: Generally speaking, Halley's Method has cubic convergence, while Newton's Method has quadratic convergence, so the results after each iteration aren't going to match. [I haven't verified that the iteration formulas above correctly reflect the Newton and Halley methods as applied to Lambert W].

Comment: @njuffa If you put that as an answer, I will accept it as the answer to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under suitable conditions, [Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method) provides cubic convergence, or a tripling of the number of correct digits between $w_j$ and $w_{j+1}$. [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) provides only quadratic convergence, or a doubling of the number of correct digits between $w_j$ and $w_{j+1}$.

Since the two methods are frequently interchangeable (meaning that for a given root, the conditions for convergence are met for both methods), one would therefore prefer the use of Halley's method if $f^{\prime\prime}$ exists and is sufficiently easy to compute.

The Wikipedia entry for Halley's method referenced above shows alternative ways of expressing the iteration which demonstrate the relationship with Newton's method and possibly provide improved computational characteristics such as efficiency or accuracy.

Given the different rate of convergence of these two methods, combining them in some fashion does not seem advisable.